# How do I configure Java EE running on GAE to work with Angular UI Router in html5Mode?

Tags: angularjs, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, angular-ui-router

I am attempting to set the UI Router location provider html5Mode to true for my Angular application: `locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`. While this works client side (appropriately redirects) I am running into issues server side. I am running an instance Java Enterprise Edition on Google App Engine.

I have configured my `web.xml` as outlined for [Java EE section in the Angular `ui-router` FAQ](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">
   <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/</location>
   </error-page>
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>services</param-name>
            <param-value>
                <!-- stuff specific to my GAE app -->
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Sadly even with the above configuration when I browse to client based routes I am still receiving a 404 error from the server. I have tried various values (`/index.html`, `index.html`) for the `error-page > location` element with the same result.

I am probably missing something obvious in my configuration, but am at a loss to what I am doing wrong.

Comment: By any chance, have you set the base in your HTML-file as `<head> <base href="/"> </head>`?
Additionally, can you post a minimal working example of your code so we can reproduce this issue on our end?

Comment: Do you have your angular app statically sent from within your app.yaml or are you having your Java EE app serve all assets?

Comment: @ahsteele, I'm facing the same issue, found any solution?

Comment: @Rishi I haven't. Currently hosting elsewhere and doing a CORS request back to GAE.

Comment: I've fixed this in the past by by creating a servlet filter to catch the 404s and respond with the contents of `index.html`